# Native IE9 not behaving like IE9 in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11

What is the best way to find out my browser is "Native IE9 (Only IE9 installed, not changed document mode from IE11 to IE9)".

SCENARIO:
I have two machines, both are having Windows7 OS. But, one machine has Native IE9, other machine has IE11. My testing team raised an issue out of these browsers.

ISSUE:
Native IE9 not behaving like IE9 changed mode from IE11 to IE9.

EXPECTED:
Would like to know how to detect Native IE9 browser.

Comment: Really the question should be, "What is the code doing that differs between "real IE9" and "IE11 in IE9 mode"? To know that we'd need to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to say this (as I don't believe the answer will help you much in the long run), but you can use the [Trident token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx#TriToken) of the user-agent string to determine the version of IE that's actually running.

This is a [dangerous practice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx), one that will likely get [more complex](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/11/11/living-on-the-edge-our-next-step-in-interoperability.aspx) as time goes on.

Perhaps a better question is to ask why you need to distinguish between versions?  For troubleshooting purposes, you can use the [F12 tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182326(v=vs.85)) to investigate individual cases.

You didn't indicate what sort of behavioral differences you're seeing between the two machines.  As a result, it's hard to recommend more appropriate alternatives.  You may find the [IE Compatibility  Cookbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384059(vs.85)) helpful, as it outlines some of the [major changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn467846(v=vs.85).aspx) in recent versions of IE (as well as a few of [the minor ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn467845(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Hope this helps...

-- Lance